# Why does the child ComboBox performs dual action whenever I change the selected item from its parent ComboBox.?

Tags: javafx, combobox

I have this nested Combobox, that whenever I selected something from the parent Combobox, the items from the child Combobox changes. At first try, it performs exactly what I want it to be. But when I change the selected value of the parent Combobox, the child Combobox double its action.

For example, when I selected the child Combobox, it will display "Me". But whenever I change the parent and then select the child again, it will display "Me" twice, which is supposed to be only once.

Here is my code.

```
cdata = ComboBoxCaller.getCityMun("PH-NCR");
cmbCit.setItems(cdata);
cmbCit.setConverter(new StringConverter<City_Municipality>() {
    @Override
    public String toString(City_Municipality object) {
        return object.getCityName();
    }

    @Override
    public City_Municipality fromString(String string) {
        return cmbCit.getItems().stream().filter(ap -> ap.getCityName().equals(string)).findFirst().orElse(null);
    }
});

pdata = ComboBoxCaller.getProvince();
cmbProv.setItems(pdata);
cmbProv.setConverter(new StringConverter<Province>() {
    @Override
    public String toString(Province object) {
        return object.getPname();
    }

    @Override
    public Province fromString(String string) {
        return cmbProv.getItems().stream().filter(ap -> ap.getPname().equals(string)).findFirst().orElse(null);
    }
});

cmbProv.valueProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Province> obs, Province oldval, Province newval) -> {
    if (newval != null) {
        System.out.println("Selected: " + newval.getPname() + ". ID: " + newval.getPcode());
        prov_nm = newval.getPname();

        // Setting up list of Cities and Municipality
        cdata = ComboBoxCaller.getCityMun(newval.getPcode());
        cmbCit.setItems(cdata);
        cmbCit.setConverter(new StringConverter<City_Municipality>() {
            @Override
            public String toString(City_Municipality object) {
                return object.getCityName();
            }

            @Override
            public City_Municipality fromString(String string) {
                return cmbCit.getItems().stream().filter(ap -> ap.getCityName().equals(string)).findFirst().orElse(null);
            }
        });

        // this is where the bug/error occurs
        cmbCit.valueProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends City_Municipality> option, City_Municipality old, City_Municipality newVal) -> {
            if (newVal != null) {
                city_nm = newVal.getCityName();
                cit_id = newVal.getPkCit();
                System.out.println("City: " + city_nm + " City ID: " + cit_id);
                isDisable(false);   // disable

                //Setting up list of Sub-Municipalities
                smdata = ComboBoxCaller.getSubMun(newVal.getPkCit());
                cmbSubMun.setItems(smdata);
                cmbSubMun.setConverter(new StringConverter<Sub_Municipality>() {
                    @Override
                    public String toString(Sub_Municipality object) {
                        return object.getSub_mun();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Sub_Municipality fromString(String string) {
                        return cmbSubMun.getItems().stream().filter(ap -> ap.getSub_mun().equals(string)).findFirst().orElse(null);
                    }
                });

                cmbSubMun.valueProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Sub_Municipality> opt, Sub_Municipality od, Sub_Municipality nw) -> {
                    if (nw != null) {
                        sub_vil = nw.getSub_mun();
                        subMun = nw.getSub_mun();
                    }
                });

                //Setting up list of Subdivisions and Village
                sdata = ComboBoxCaller.getSubVil(newVal.getPkCit());
                cmbSub.setItems(sdata);
                cmbSub.setConverter(new StringConverter<Subdivision_Village>() {
                    @Override
                    public String toString(Subdivision_Village object) {
                        return object.getSub_vil();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Subdivision_Village fromString(String string) {
                        return cmbSub.getItems().stream().filter(ap -> ap.getSub_vil().equals(string)).findFirst().orElse(null);
                    }
                });

                cmbSub.valueProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Subdivision_Village> opt, Subdivision_Village od, Subdivision_Village nw) -> {
                    if (nw != null) {
                        sub_vil = nw.getSub_vil();
                    }
                });
            } else {
                isDisable(true);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

the bug/error, occurred on `cmbCit`, that whenever I change the selected value of `cmbProv`, the items of `cmbCit` changes **BUT**, whenever I select an item from `cmbCit`, it will perform twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you are adding a listener for `cmbCit.valueProperty()` inside another listener `cmbProv.valueProperty()`). Be very careful with this kind of implementation because it may raise problems : in your case, the more you will select an item in `cmbProv`, the more you will collect listeners for `cmbCit.valueProperty()`. You have to remove your listener each time you invoke `cmbCit.valueProperty()` to make sure you won't have your procedure executed several times at once.

Comment: Thank you, I really don't know how listeners work, still thank you for putting me on the right track. 

Comment: _I really don't know how listeners work_ then it's time for reading and understanding a basic tutorial on javafx (they are essential for whatever you do)